# How to use Promise.all() when I'd like to pass an array variable as an argument

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm in a problem using Promise.all().

I'd like to pass an array variable as an argument to Promise.all() like below.

```
const promArr = []
if (condition1) {
  promArr.push(() => prom1(arg1, arg2))
}
if (condition2) {
  promArr.push(() => prom2(arg1, arg2))
}
if (promArr.length > 0) Promise.all(promArr)
```

But above doesn't run the promise functions(`prom1`, `prom2`) even if conditions are all true. (`promArr.length` is as I expected)

if I push promise functions directly to `promArr`, I'm afraid they run at that time they are pushed to `promArr`, not at `Promise.all(promArr)`.

How can I use Promise properly in this case?

Comment: `Promise.all` expects an array of promises, not an array of promise-returning functions. Why did you try to wrap them?

Comment: You can (and should) call `Promise.all` on empty arrays as well. No need for `if (promArr.length > 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `promArr` variable is just fine. However (as the name suggests), it should be an array of promises, not an array of functions that return promises.

```
const promArr = []
if (condition1) {
  promArr.push(prom1(arg1, arg2))
}
if (condition2) {
  promArr.push(prom2(arg1, arg2))
}
return Promise.all(promArr)
```

> if I push promise functions directly to `promArr`, I'm afraid they run at that time they are pushed to `promArr`, not at `Promise.all(promArr)`.

`Promise.all` won't run any functions, you have to do it yourself. Yes, by calling `prom1` and `prom2` immediately inside the conditional block, they will start right after the condition is evaluated, but if they're properly asynchronous and don't interfere with the following conditions that is not a problem. Notice that the promises they return are not awaited yet, they'll do their processing in parallel.

Comment: I'd just like to use Promise.all(promArr).then().catch(). Is .then().catch() valid in above case?

Comment: Yes, exactly that (assuming you're passing any callbacks to `then` and `catch`).

Comment: Clear. Thx very much.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), *`Promise.all()` returns a single Promise that resolves when all of **the promises** in the iterable argument have resolved [...]*.

Try to push Promises :

```
promArr.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(p1, p2);
}));
```

If I use your example, I get :

```
const p1 = 1;
const p2 = 2;
const promArr = [];

if (condition1)
  promArr.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(p1, p2);
}));

if (condition2)
  promArr.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(p1, p2);
}));

Promise.all(promArr);
```

> if I push promise functions directly to promArr, I'm afraid they run
>   at that time they are pushed to promArr, not at Promise.all(promArr).

If you want to run all functions at Promise.all, you can do something like that :

```
const p1 = 1;
const p2 = 2;
const promArr = [];

if (condition1)
  promArr.push(() => prom1(arg1, arg2));
if (condition2)
  promArr.push(() => prom1(arg1, arg2));

Promise.all(promArr.map((prom) => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(prom()))));
```

Here, the `.map` transform the array of function into an array of promises who is given to the Promise.all().

That's a bit tricky but it's working.

Comment: Thx for answer. I noticed that this problem matters the promArr contains Promise.resolve() or Promise.reject(), not mattering when the promise functions run. This solution is for when promise runs, and codes are more complex. So I choose simpler one. Anyway, still this is good solution if problem matters when Promise functions run. Good job!!